# Python Daemon calling a subprocess periodically

Tags: python, subprocess, python-daemon

I am building a simple pyhon daemon based on [Sander Marechal's](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) code. Daemon's whole purpose is to run a php file every second (php file loops through database checking values and updating database). Problem arises on the section

> subprocess.call(['php','test.php'])

I can run "php test.php" on shell and it does what it is suppose to do but when it is called periodically from the daemon it doesn't seem to be executed. I also know daemon works on the background via checking running process ps aux | grep "daemon-example" also i included a do_something function which records every time function executed and appends time to a text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, time,subprocess
from daemon import Daemon


def runphp():
    #subprocess.call(['php ~/pydaemon/test.php'], shell=True)
    subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py'])
def do_something():
    with open("/tmp/current_time.txt",'a') as f:
        f.write("The time is now\n" + time.ctime())

class MyDaemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            do_something()
            subprocess.call(['php','test.php'])
            #runphp()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print "Unknown command"
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you are trying to run is not executed because the working directory is the root directory `('/')` and that's because of this piece of code:

```
# decouple from parent environment
os.chdir("/")
```

So actually your code tries to execute: `python /test.py`(which does not exist) and not `'your_current_directory/test.py'`.
To fix it either remove `os.chdir("/")`, or provide the full path to the file like so:

```
subprocess.call(['python','my_full_path_to_working_directory/test.py'])
```

Comment: Where do you see the os.chdir("/")? I tried giving the full path for the test.py(like so: /root/pydaemon/test.py) but no luck.

Comment: it's in the script you used, in the Daemon class.(line 34)

Comment: What happens if you remove os.chdir("/")?